# How to get data for below scenario?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 4 tables.

Employee:

```
Id|emp_start_date|Public_id|
01|00-00-00      |001
02|00-00-00      |002
```

Person:

```
Id|Public_id|name|...
01|001      |aaaa|..
02|002      |bbbb|...
```

pay_info:

```
public_id|current_pay_year
001|2015
002|2015
```

Ni_table:

```
public_id|Ni_letter_code|Niable_pay|ni_a|ni_b|ni_c|ni_d|year
001      |A             |890        |12 | 12 | 0  | 0  |2015
002      |A             |500        |14 |14  |0   | 0  |2015
002      |A             |600        |14 |14  |0   | 0  |2015
002      |B             |400        |13 | 13 |0   |0   |2015
002      |B             |500        |13 | 13 |0   |0   |2015
```

I want to get the Sum of niable_pay and all other columns by using ni_letter_code for the year 2015.

I want to get all the employees details for current pay year.
But When the employee has two ni letter code, then he should have 2 row for them.
Each row should have the addition value for the respective ni_code.

Expected output:

```
01|A| 890|12|12|0|0|2015
02|A|1100|25|28|0|0|2015
02|B| 900|26|26|0|0|2015
```

My query:

```
select
  e.id,
  NI.Ni_letter_code,
  SUM(NI.Niable_pay),
  SUM(ni_a),
  SUM(ni_b),
  SUM(ni_c),
  SUM(ni_d),
  ni.year 
from 
  employee e 
  JOIN  person P ON e.id=P.id
  INNER JOIN pay_info PI ON PI.public_id = E.public_id
  INNER JOIN Ni_table NI ON NI.public_id  = E.public_id 
    AND NI.year =  PI.current_pay_year
```

Comment: It's not clear what you would like to do. Please post some sample data and  you desire output.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: This sounds a lot like you need a dynamic crosstab or dynamic pivot.

Comment: the third row of expected output... where did you get `tax_amount=3000` from?

Comment: Oh,sorry,just edited it.

Comment: Based on sample data, your desired output is just a `SELECT *` from the Tax table.

Comment: For tax table I use public_id,

Comment: Why do you use SUM? I see no sums in your example.

Comment: To get the sum of tax for each tax_code,I use tax.

Comment: I edited with full details.Please some one help here.

Comment: What does your actual output look like?

Comment: As before, if you have a query with SUM() in it, you need to have a GROUP BY of all the columns that are not aggregated.   I suggest you google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to think that by stating

```
select
  e.id,
  NI.Ni_letter_code,
  SUM(NI.Niable_pay),
  SUM(ni_a),
  SUM(ni_b),
  SUM(ni_c),
  SUM(ni_d),
  ni.year
```

you get a result record per `e.id`, `NI.Ni_letter_code` and `ni.year` along with the desired sums.

This is not the case. SQL doesn't aggregate by non-aggregated columns implicitely. You must make the aggregation group explicit with `GROUP BY`. So in order to get one result record per `e.id`, `NI.Ni_letter_code` and `ni.year` you'd add:

```
group by e.id, NI.Ni_letter_code, ni.year
```

at the end of your query:

```
select
  e.id,
  NI.Ni_letter_code,
  SUM(NI.Niable_pay),
  SUM(ni_a),
  SUM(ni_b),
  SUM(ni_c),
  SUM(ni_d),
  ni.year 
from 
  employee e 
  JOIN  person P ON e.id=P.id
  INNER JOIN pay_info PI ON PI.public_id = E.public_id
  INNER JOIN Ni_table NI ON NI.public_id  = E.public_id 
    AND NI.year =  PI.current_pay_year
group by e.id, NI.Ni_letter_code, ni.year;
```